# Can a groovy script inherit from a Java or Groovy superclass?

Tags: java, groovy

Here is the script (Scccc.groovy):

```
import scriptParents.ScriptGroovyParent

println(queryThisBaby("my query"));
```

and here is the superclass:

```
class ScriptGroovyParent {

    public ScriptGroovyParent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

//  public String queryThisBaby(String query){
//      
//      return query +" was run.";
//  }

    def queryThisBaby(name) {
        return name +" was run."
    }
}
```

I get an error though when trying to run the script.

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: scripts.Scccc.queryThisBaby() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [my query]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: scripts.Scccc.queryThisBaby() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [my query]
    at scripts.Scccc.run(Scccc.groovy:5)
```

How can this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A script can extend a base class using [CompilerConfiguration](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilerConfiguration.html). The caveat here is that base class has to extend [Script](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html) as groovy scripts extend Script normally and you cannot have multiple inheritance in a "IS A" relationship.

```
//ScriptGroovyParent.groovy
abstract class ScriptGroovyParent extends Script{
    def queryThisBaby(name) {
        return name +" was run."
    }
}


//Script Scccc.groovy
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

def configuration = new CompilerConfiguration()
configuration.setScriptBaseClass("ScriptGroovyParent")

def shell = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, new Binding(), configuration)

assert shell.evaluate("queryThisBaby('My Query')") == 'My Query was run.'
```

You can import the package if they both reside in different packages.

Comment: thanks, but what about the                                                            @Override
 public Object run() {
  return null;
 }                                                                 method from the Script class.

Comment: That is overriden in the script. The script (a groovy script in general) which creates the shell and evaluates the expression in the above case will always be runnable and run under `run()` from Script. If you want to make sure it is always done that way and not from the parent than declare `ScriptGroovyParent` as `abstract`. @AlexMills